# Es posible darle un formato a JtextField y que se ejecute una acción si se cumple el formato?

Tags: java, netbeans

Ejemplo:

Tengo un programa para la gestión de un parqueadero en el cual en un JTexField se recibe la placa o matricula del vehiculo que va a ingresar, en mi país las matriculas se categorizan de 3 maneras.

1. XXX### (tres letras y tres números para los automóviles).
2. XXX##X (tres letras, dos números y finaliza con una letra para el caso de las motocicletas).
3. XXXX## (4 Letras y dos números para las bicicletas)

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que al ingresar la matricula en el jtextfield y darle enter me identifique que formato tiene y asi me seleccione si es automóvil,motocicleta o bicicleta.

He intentando de muchas maneras pero aun no lo logro enserio agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: *He intentando de muchas maneras..* Pon lo que tengas hecho en la pregunta y especifica cual es el problema con tu código.